# How to get HTML resource of a page by php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, curl

I wanted to make my site let anyone when open internal links, the links open on the current page without opening new `url` in browser (something like what happens in Instagram site).
For doing this I wanted to use `jQuery`/`Ajax` to make `XMLHttpRequest` to a `php` file that will prepare the new page `HTML Data` so I started making a `php` file that returns a `url` resources to use them in my old page:

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents("http://example.com");
echo $html;
?>
```

It worked! so let me use my own link in that simple script:

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents("http://apps.bestbadboy.ir/solver");
echo $html;
?>
```

It doesn't work! I searched in google and stackoverflow for its reason, I got some sites doesn't allow to use this method and maybe curl help me! so let me use **`curl`**:

```
<?php
        function curl($url){
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0');
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $data;
        }

echo curl('http://apps.bestbadboy.ir/solver');
?>
```

so after all it finally doesn't work again:(

I started searching but I found nothing! I just guess I should edit `.htaccess` file or put something in my `url`(s) that I want to copy them to grant access to `php` file that will do that. please help me how to make my site at this way (like Instagram opening its internal links)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very Well! I found my solution! after searching very much and trying many ways I found my problem! using `curl` is a good method for getting a **HTML page source code**, but the problem that was making this way not to work for me is I had edited `.htaccess` file to redirect `http` requests to `https`! and **`curl function`** I used doesn't support that redirect! so I put my `url` with `https` format and it worked very nice!

```
<?php
        function curl($url){
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0');
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $data;
        }

echo curl('https://apps.bestbadboy.ir/solver');
?>
```